# Chromium Installation Problem

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, chromium

I run `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` on terminal to install chromium. I got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  chromium-browser
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/48.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 164 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package chromium-browser.
(Reading database ... 210209 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../chromium-browser_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
=> Installing the chromium snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
==> Installing the chromium snap
error: cannot install "chromium": cannot query the store for updates: got
       unexpected HTTP status code 408 via POST to
       "https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh"
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/chromium-browser_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new chromium-browser package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/chromium-browser_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to install chromium browser on my laptop ? I tried many thing from internet. Nothing really works

Answer (score 0):

Running the following actually helped me:

```
sudo service snapd restart
sudo snap set system proxy.http=""
sudo snap set system proxy.https=""
sudo snap refresh
sudo snap install snap-shop
sudo snap install snapd
```

Notice that the `snap` and `snapd` snaps are installed in the last line. After this, I could install any snap I wanted. I believe something went wrong during the Upgrade of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS.

If this fails again, one can download the snaps manually by:

```
sudo snap download snap-shop
sudo snap download snapd
```

Following the instructions printed, you can now install them by:

```
snap ack snapd_16778.assert
snap install snapd_16778.snap
snap ack snapd-shop_60.assert
snap install snap-shop_60.snap
```

Note that the revision numbers (filename suffixes) may change.

Answer (score -1):

The error: "unexpected HTTP status code 408 via POST" means the snap store server did not receive the complete request from the client within the server's allotted time.
The error code: "Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)" means corrupt dpkg database.
I suggest following terminal commands to resolve the issues.
Reconfigure dpkg by the command

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Fix the broken packages by the command

```
sudo apt install--fix-broken
```

Install the chromium from the ubuntu repositories instead of the snap store.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```